# Get values in LWC Helper from apex response as JSON.serialize

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I am trying to access values in LWC contoller.JS the response which it returned from apex method response.

This is the response. [image]

How can i access totalHours and entids in controller.Js
Already i decalared variables as @track property.
But not able to get it. This is what i tried so far.

```
@wire(remainingBlockHours, { CustomerAccountId: '$caseCustomerAccId', billingCountry: '$serviceAppointment_Countryvalue' })
remainingBlockHours({ error, data }) {
    console.log('Return response - ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    // this.accountList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    //console.log('accountList==' + this.accountList);
    this.responsedata = JSON.stringify(data);
    this.totalHours = this.responsedata;
    alert(this.totalHours);
```

Comment: It is very unlikely that your component intends to consume these values from a JSON string, which is what you are storing right now.

Comment: Hi @davidReed, How can i access totalHours from the above response. ; If i try to access something like this - i am getting error .  var totalhoursvalue = this.responsedata.totalHours;

Answer (score 2):

The alert is showing that you serialized a JSON string. You'll want to parse it instead:

```
this.responsedata = JSON.parse(data);
```

FYI, if you had returned a native object (e.g. Map) from Apex, you wouldn't need the extra parsing step here. You may want to consider revising your Apex so that your code simply reads:

```
this.responsedata = data;
```

The total hours would come from the data:

```
this.totalHours = this.responsedata.totalHours;
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox,  Here i am getting this issue, while trying to access totalHours data.  this.responsedata = JSON.parse(data);
        this.totalHours = this.responsedata.totalHours;
        alert(this.totalHours);  
  This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error during LWC component constructor phase: [LWC component's @_wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error: [Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0]] Failing descriptor:

Comment: From the Apex method am sending response as a String format of wrapper class data.  In apex returened response as String strJSON = JSON.serialize(temp); ,                  
 This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error during LWC component constructor phase: [LWC component's @_wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error: [Cannot read property 'totalHours' of undefined]] Failing descriptor: error occurred when trying to access totalHours. this.responsedata = JSON.stringify(data);
  this.totalHours = this.responsedata.totalHours;